# (FREERADIUS&MYSQL) Getting aborted connections to my db (got an error reading communication packets)

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb, freeradius, freeradius2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUI2n.png

Running Debian 11, 1 week trying to figure out where this issue comes from, tried authentication method (made a fresh install of mariadb, setting unix socket so radius won't even have to give a pass since my vm is always in sudo mode), package size, looking into logs but no clue, the server is working locally with test users but when i indicate a db managed through daloradius i'm getting this.

I can only think about trying to set it up on another distrib since all the videos i see are on ubuntuserver.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Please post text, not images

Comment: Please don't share images/screen shots but actual error messages.